Finding old rf components datasheets
I've just received a load of old rf components used for X-W band and am at a loss for where to find information on them. A lot of the parts are from TRG division of Alpha Industries Inc. and it seems like the company no longer exists. I've looked up the part numbers and the company and have found no relevant information. Any suggestions?
Some part numbers (same company as above): 62185100, W600, W528, W9600-12, 60550200.

Are they transistors, diodes, tubes?

They're amplifiers, attenuators, mixers, couplers etc. They're also waveguide components.
